# Shell comparing two list, and output the difference on a third list

Tags: shell, text-processing, file-comparison

I have two text files, a.txt and b.txt where:

a.txt

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

b.txt

```
3
5
```

I'd like to have c.txt where matching numbers will be printed "0" and non matching numbers to be "1".

```
1
1
0
1
0
```

I understand that comm can suppress/ print unique lines but how do I get around to get the c.txt as above?

Many thanks.

Comment: yeah, I'm sure it is, I'm just really bad at it :)

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to mess around with `diff` and not join here's another option.

`sdiff -l a.txt b.txt | sed -e 's/.*<.*/1/' -e 's/.*(.*/0/'`

You could probably get some better `sed` expression in there or change it up using `awk` but it's a quick shot, then just redirect this to `c.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Use `awk` on the `comm` output:

```
$ comm a.txt b.txt | awk -F'\t' '$1 || $2 { print 1 } $3 { print 0 }'
```

`comm` will output three tab-separated columns:

1. lines only in the first file,
2. lines only in the second file, and
3. lines present in both files.

The `awk` script will classify any input that has something in either of the first two columns as a "mismatch" and output `1`, and if there's something in the third column it will output `0` for a match.

Note that `comm` requires the two files to be sorted.

Comment: One potential problem is that comm expects its inputs in LC_COLLATE order, so you may have to sort first if input file contains, say, both 1 and 10

Answer (score 2):

As don_crissti pointed out, with `awk` it's pretty simple:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { match_nmbrs[$1]++; next;}
             {if($1 in match_nmbrs)
                  print 0;
              else
                  print 1; }
    ' b.txt a.txt
```

The first `{...}` condition works eclusively on records in the first file, while the second `{...}` condition works exclusively on records in the second file. All other things are self-explaining imo.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another `awk` solution

```
awk '1,$0=system("grep -qx "$1" b.txt")' a.txt
```